# change position of word within a string in r

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a string vector that looks like:

```
> string_vec
 [1] "XXX"                     "Snakes On A Plane"       "Mask of the Ninja"       "Ruslan"                 
 [5] "Kill Switch"             "Buddy Holly Story, The"  "Believers, The"          "Closet, The"            
 [9] "Eyes of Tammy Faye, The" "Gymnast, The"            "Hunger, The"
```

There are some names which contain ", The" in the end. I want to delete the comma and the space and move the "The" before all other text.

For e.g.: "Buddy Holly Story, The" becomes "The Buddy Holly Story".

Isolating the records with the pattern was easy :

```
string_vec[grepl("[Aa-zZ]+, The", string_vec) == TRUE]
```

How can I adjust the position now?

#### data

```
string_vec <- c("XXX", "Snakes On A Plane", "Mask of the Ninja", 
"Ruslan", 
"Kill Switch", "Buddy Holly Story, The", "Believers, The", 
"Closet, The", 
"Eyes of Tammy Faye, The", "Gymnast, The", "Hunger, The")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may try

```
sub('^(.*), The', 'The \\1', string_vec)
#[1] "XXX"                    "Snakes On A Plane"      "Mask of the Ninja"     
#[4] "Ruslan"                 "Kill Switch"            "The Buddy Holly Story" 
#[7] "The Believers"          "The Closet"             "The Eyes of Tammy Faye"
#[10] "The Gymnast"            "The Hunger"
```

Comment: this works! thanks. I didn't know the \\1 can be used to refer to position within string in `regex`.

Comment: @vagabond We are capturing the group before the `, The` and use that to replace `\\1`

Comment: @vagabond That is the first capture group inside the parentheses.  Suppose if there are two capture groups, we refer it as `\\1 \\2` and so on.  For example, `sub('^(.*), (The)', '\\2 \\1', string_vec)` , here `The` is the second capture group

Comment: Very nice answer, akrun.

Comment: aah . . ok. Got it ! so we can even do - `\\1 The \\2` if we want to . . is there any other way of subsetting characters within string - like - `string_vec[[2]]` which can give Snakes in "Snakes On A Plane" ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, do you have any suggestions to improve

Comment: @vagabond Not sure I understand your question.  Do you need to extract the `Snakes`.  `str_extract(string_vec[2], 'Snakes')#[1] "Snakes"` from `stringr`

Comment: I want to extract Snakes just by its position - i.e. first word in the second element of string_vec. don't want to use 'Snakes' like you did in str_extract. This is off topic - just a thought.

Comment: If you need the first word, try `word(string_vec,1)` or `sub('^(\\w+).*$', '\\1', string_vec)`

Comment: I didn't know about `\\1`, that's very neat. I'd probably have used dummy variables or something even uglier than that.

Comment: @Molx Thanks for the comment.  The capture groups can be used for rearranging

Comment: And I thought I had learned the big secret of regex when I learned about capture groups a few weaks ago... This is really helpful!

Comment: @vagabond Or `sub('[^A-Za-z]+.*$', '', string_vec)`