# Conditional shift of substring position in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

```
> Df1
[1] "HM_004_T"    "HM_004_T2"   "HM_005_T"    "HMFN_005_T2" "HM_007_T"    "HM_007_T2"   "HM_088_TR"  
[8] "HM_088_T3"
```

Reference is made to [change position of word within a string in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055961/change-position-of-word-within-a-string-in-r). I have a slightly different question. I first wish to delete `_T` if it presents on its own, and wish to delete `_T2`, `_T3` or `_TR` and move them before all other text.

My ideal output will be:

```
Df1 <- c("HM_004", "T2_HM_004", "HM_005", "T2_HM_005", "HM_007", "T2_HM_007", "TR_HM_088", "T3_HM_088")
```

Input data

```
Df1 <- c("HM_004_T", "HM_004_T2", "HM_005_T", "HM_005_T2", "HM_007_T", "HM_007_T2", "HM_088_TR", "HM_088_T3")
```

Comment: Are the patterns `_T` and `_T"` always occurring at the end of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with nested `sub` and backreference:

```
DF1 <- sub("(.*)_(T\\w)$", "\\2_\\1", sub("_T$", "", DF1))
```

Here you delete string-final `_T` in the first `sub` operation, the result of which you pass to the second `sub` operation, which switches the order of (i) whatever comes before the underscore `_` and (ii) `T` followed by a digit or a letter (`\\w`), by referring to these two substrings with the backreferences `\\1`and `\\2`.

Result:

```
DF1 
[1] "HM_004"    "T2_HM_004" "HM_005"    "T2_HM_005" "HM_007"    "T2_HM_007" "TR_HM_088" "T3_HM_088"
```

Data:

```
DF1 <- c("HM_004_T", "HM_004_T2", "HM_005_T", "HM_005_T2", 
         "HM_007_T", "HM_007_T2", "HM_088_TR", "HM_088_T3")
```

Comment: Many thanks, the codes and the explanations are helpful, however `HM_088_TR` got left out and didn't get switched.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this relatively easy with the package **stringr** and the functions `str_remove()` and `str_replace()`.

I am assuming that the patterns of interest always occur at the end of the text and that they are always preceded by `_`.

Please, have a look at the *updated* code below. This treats the pattern `_T*`, where `*` can now be a letter, as target thus good pattern.

```r
library(stringr)
Df1 <- c("HM_004_T", "HM_004_T2", "HM_005_T", "HM_005_T2", 
         "HM_007_T", "HM_007_T2", "HM_088_TR", "HM_088_T3")

# Here I remove the roots I don't want like "_T" and "_T*" 
# where "*" can be a digit or a character
df2 <- str_remove(Df1, "_T$")

# Here I replace the patterns through the group reference
final <- str_replace( df2, "(^.*)_(T\\d+$|T\\w+$)", "\\2_\\1" )
final
#> [1] "HM_004"    "T2_HM_004" "HM_005"    "T2_HM_005" "HM_007"    "T2_HM_007"
#> [7] "TR_HM_088" "T3_HM_088"

# A more coincise way would be the following where \\w is the workhorse.
final <- str_replace( df2, "(^.*)_(T\\w$)", "\\2_\\1" )
final
#> [1] "HM_004"    "T2_HM_004" "HM_005"    "T2_HM_005" "HM_007"    "T2_HM_007"
#> [7] "TR_HM_088" "T3_HM_088"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Does this work for you?

Comment: This worked well, too, providing me another approach to work with. I actually wished that `HM_088_TR` could get corrected as well, to `TR_HM_088`.

Comment: No need for `\\d+$|T\\w$` as `\\w`matches letters *and* digits (and, yes, the underscore too)!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann good point. I can update my reply with just `T\\w$`.