# Rearrange a string using regex

Tags: r

I have an expression as a string, like the following:

```r
orig <- "mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)"
orig
#> [1] "mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)"
```

I would like to rearrange this string so that I get the following output:

```r
"Sepal.Length$mean(na.rm = TRUE)"
#> [1] "Sepal.Length$mean(na.rm = TRUE)"
```

I know that I can use capture groups like this:

```r
gsub("(Sepal.Length)", "\\1\\$", orig)
#> [1] "mean(Sepal.Length$, na.rm = TRUE)"
```

but this doesn’t work to move text in the string:

```r
gsub("(Sepal.Length)(.*)", "\\1\\$\\2", orig)
#> [1] "mean(Sepal.Length$, na.rm = TRUE)"
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055961/change-position-of-word-within-a-string-in-r) was helpful but the solution there is hardcoded, whereas here I don't know the expression I will have at all, just that it will contain `Sepal.Length`. The expression above could be `"sum(Sepal.Length)"` for example.

I’m looking for a solution **in base R only**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
gsub("(.+)\\(Sepal\\.Length,? *(.*)\\)", "Sepal.Length$\\1(\\2)", orig)
```

- `(.+)` matches anything before the first parenthesis `\\(`;
- Then, we always have "Sepal.Length". Note that `.` is a special character, so to use a literal dot you need `\\.`;
- We then might have a comma, and space(s) `,? *` (`?` means "0 or 1 times", and `*` means "0 or more times");
- After that we might have the other arguments `(.*)`, followed by the closing parenthesis `\\)`.

Edit: Thanks for @rps1227 for the suggested improvements.

Comment: This solution won't work if there is no comma after `Sepal.Length` like in the case of `sum(Sepal.Length)` as specified in the question

Comment: This regex: `gsub("(.+)\\(Sepal\\.Length(, )*(.*)\\)", "Sepal.Length$\\1(\\3)", orig)` seems to work with that case too.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the expression giving `p` in which case p[[2]] is `Sepal.Length` in the first example but could be something else as in the second exxample.  Then convert p to a list and NULL out the 2nd element which is Sepal.Length in the first example and then convert that to a call object and from that to a string.  Finally paste p[[2]] onto the front of it using $ as the separator.  No packages or regular expressions are used and it is independent of whether the first argument name is `Sepal.Length` or something else.

```
f <- function(orig) {
  p <- str2lang(orig)
  paste(p[[2]], format(as.call(replace(as.list(p), 2, NULL))), sep = "$")
}

orig <- "mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)"
f(orig)
## [1] "Sepal.Length$mean(na.rm = TRUE)"

orig2 <- "sum(Sepal.Width)"
f(orig2)
## [1] "Sepal.Width$sum()"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know `"Sepal.Length"` in advance then you don't need regex to stick it on the front, you can `paste` it there:

```
pattern = "Sepal.Length"

result = sub(pattern = paste0(pattern, ", "), replacement = "", x = orig, fixed = TRUE)
result = paste0(pattern, "$", result)
result
# [1] "Sepal.Length$mean(na.rm = TRUE)"
```